# TS/JS if statement does not execute

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom

I have a function to animate a background and create an illusion of endless movement. For some reason, when called, the image does several fast "loops" and goes away, and console.log'ging the coordinates shows that they endlessly decrease below -2400. For some reason, even though I have those if statements which should reset x and x2 to appropriate values, it does not happen.

```
let x = 0;
let x2 = 2400;

function animateFullBackground(speed: number) {
    clear();
    for (let layer of background) {
        // Draw two images of one layer of background next to each other
        ctx.drawImage(layer, x, 0);
        ctx.drawImage(layer, x2, 0);
    }

    console.log(x, x2)

    if (x < -2400) {
        x = 2400; // move image1 to right position
    }

    if (x2 < -2400) {
        x2 = 2400; // move image2 to right position
    }

    x -= speed;
    x2 -= speed;

    requestAnimationFrame(animateFullBackground);
}

function clear() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);    
}

clear();
animateFullBackground(1);
```

Explanation: I have a background variable, which is an array of background layers, but for testing purposes I use only one layer, hence, there is only one element in this array. ctx is a 2d context of HTML canvas.

Comment: *Tangential: when you `requestAnimationFrame(animateFullBackground)` what do you think `speed` will be?*

Comment: @DaveNewton seems like I wrote an ambiguity here, thanks for pointing it out. Should my function not take any arguments or is there a way to pass it through requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: You can create a wrapper function for the next cycle that passes `speed` through. Something like `requestAnimationFrame(_ => animateFullBackground(speed));`

Comment: @Pointy ...seems like that solved my issue, thanks. But still, even though my speed was ambiguous, why wasn't there any error or warning and why weren't the variables reset on values below -2400? Is it just some internal misbehaviour?

Comment: There’s no error or warning because it’s JS and what you wrote is valid, but unintended.

Comment: [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) passes [DOMHighResTimeStamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) (which is a number of milliseconds from the page load) as an argument to the callback function. That's why you didn't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

you could easily solve it with some css tricks:

```
.wrapper-div{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.your-background-image {
  background: url('../../../../public/images/game/land620.png') repeat-x;
  height: 750px; //background-img height
  width: 7680px; //how long you want it to "loop" for. i did img length times 4
  animation: slide 12s linear infinite; //this is the magic.. play with it a bit
}

//some y movement based on x%
@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0px, 310px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(-620px, 300px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-1240px, 310px);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrong question I guess